# c# Saving & Closing office documents, when multiple instances/files open at once

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, ms-word

I am working on a file backup program that auto saves any open office documents. At the current time I am working with WORD and have run into a snag. I can successfully save and close an active instance of word, without any dialogs appearing, as long as only one is running. If I have multiple word document's open, the second document get's a Save As Dialog when the first one closes. Does anyone know how I can get around this or if it is possible?

Code for Saving and Closing,

```
 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

   public static bool WordClass1(string doc,string sloc)

        {

            if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") != null)

            {

                Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                Object oTrue = true;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWordApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

                int i = 0;
                i++;
                string num = i.ToString();
                Object oSaveAsFileWord = sloc;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document in oWordApp.Documents)
                {
                    if (string.Equals(document.Name, doc))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Found Document");





                        document.SaveAs(ref oSaveAsFileWord, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);



                        object doNotSaveChanges = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

                        oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    }

                }
```

return true;

Comment: Why do you use `oWordApp.ActiveDocument` rather than `document` inside your `foreach` loop?

Comment: Well for some reason that tends to work, turns out the problem with original code I posted was oWordApp.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

i was trying to close word all together before making it to the next file to save. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static bool WordClass1(string doc,string sloc)

        {

            if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") != null)

            {

                Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                Object oTrue = true;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWordApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

                int i = 0;
                i++;
                string num = i.ToString();
                Object oSaveAsFileWord = sloc;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document in oWordApp.Documents)
                {
                    if (string.Equals(document.Name, doc))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Found Document");





                        document.SaveAs(ref oSaveAsFileWord, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);



                        object doNotSaveChanges = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

                        oWordApp.Document.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: You may wish to add a comment here about **what** you changed. Blocks of code (without some commentary) tend to get downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document` rather than `oWordApp.ActiveDocument` inside your `foreach` loop.

So, for example, rather than:

```
oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
```

you should use:

```
document.Close
```